# How to pass values globally in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables, sharedpreferences

I have some values that are stored in shared prefrences and in my case when I need to use these values in different screens, I am calling them in each one of them in a method like this:

```
Future <String> getUserInfo() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String username = preferences.getString('$userID,name')?? "No name found";
    String weight = preferences.getString('$userID,weight') ?? "no wight found";
    String height = preferences.getString('$userID,height') ?? "no Height found";
    String gendertype = preferences.getString('$userID,genderType') ?? "no gender Type found";
    String birthdate = preferences.getString('$userID,dateOfBirth') ?? "no date  found";
    

    userName = username;
    userWeight = weight;
    userHeight = height;
    userGender = gendertype;
    birthDateInString = birthdate;


    return username;
  }
```

That is working fina and all and I am getting the values everytime but then this doesnt feels right. I think I should only call them once and then pass them globally between screens or somehow keep them always stored for later use.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `provider packages` https://pub.dev/packages/provider

You can store the value and call it when you need it.

```
class UserInfo extends ChangeNotifier{
  ///Implement your Data Model And Method
}
```

call

```
//If you need to update the UI  
context.watch<UserInfo>().yourValueName or Method

//If you need to not update the UI  
context.read<UserInfo>().yourValueName or Method
```

Comment: You can use provider for this, but depending on OP's needs this could be overkill since the intention is to just call it once and cache the values then reference them statically whenever they are needed. A singleton or a service locator would do just fine for that.

Comment: I concer.  You need change notification only when the data ... changes. :)